# c# read memory with pointer

Tags: c#, c, memory

I want to read memory giving its pointer as shown in the code:

```
unsafe
   {
      int* p1 = (int*)(0x0022fe44);
      Console.WriteLine(*p1);              
   }
```

The pointer value given in the code is taken from another program which is written in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptam, tam = 33;

    printf("size of int = %d",sizeof(int)); //=>4 byte
    while(1==1)
    {
       ptam = &tam;    

       printf("&tam  = %p\n",&tam);
       printf("ptam  = %p\n",ptam);
       printf("\n");

       printf("tam   = %d\n",tam);
       printf("*ptam = %d\n",*ptam);
       printf("\n");

       *ptam = 44;     

       printf("tam   = %d\n",tam);
       printf("*ptam = %d\n",*ptam);
       sleep(10);
   }

 return 0;
}
```

Output console of C:
[Click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRgI4.png)

This give me error => Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: You cannot simply read (or write) some memory location from another program on any modern operating system. What are you _actually_ trying to do ?

Comment: You do realize that each program has its own virtual address space and that even if you got this to work you would be reading 2 different physical locations?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I just want to make program which also written c# and c.I want to take value of variable of c from memory given by its pointer address.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok.Is there a way to read memory of another program by given its pointer?

Comment: @eoweww you probably need [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) (Windows specific).